# Sucess notification animation extra arguments error SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm getting an error when trying to do the animation:

```
SuccessNotificationView()
    .offset(y: self.showSuccessSave ? -UIScreen.main.bounds.height/3 : -UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    .animation(.interactiveSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 100.0, damping: 10, initialVelocity: 0))
```

where SuccessNotificationView() is:

```
struct SuccessNotificationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Success")
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(20)
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is: Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3, #4 in call

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the the proper parameters to interactiveSpring().

```
.animation(
  .interactiveSpring(
    response: Double, 
    dampingFraction: Double,
    blendDuration: Double
  )
)
```

There are only two method calls for interactiveSpring(). One is with no parameters and the second is the example shown above.

I believe that you are trying to use **interpolatingSpring()**. In that case, use the following code snippet:

```
.animation(
  .interpolatingSpring(
    mass: 1, 
    stiffness: 100.0,
    damping: 10,
    initialVelocity: 0
  )
)
```